# an error shows when I try to install submit50

Tags: cmd, windows-10-desktop

```
C:\Users\BISMILLAH>pip install submit50

Collecting submit50



Using cached submit50-3.0.2.tar.gz (5.5 kB)
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\bismillah\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\BISMILLAH\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-enj227ls\\submit50\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\BISMILLAH\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-enj227ls\\submit50\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\BISMILLAH\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-enj227ls\submit50\pip-egg-info'
     cwd: C:\Users\BISMILLAH\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-enj227ls\submit50\
Complete output (5 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\BISMILLAH\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-enj227ls\submit50\setup.py", line 2, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError("submit50 does not support Windows directly. Instead, you should install the Windows Subsystem for Linux (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) and then install submit50 within that.")
RuntimeError: submit50 does not support Windows directly. Instead, you should install the Windows Subsystem for Linux (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) and then install submit50 within that.
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out submit50 doesn't run on Windows but this solution worked for me:

https://github.com/cs50/submit50/issues/196#issuecomment-617907204